# Why use many view controllers to make app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, view

Is it possible if we can create many views for one controller and use less number of view controller to make app. So, lets suppose we have 4 view controllers at a moment and each view controllers contains 4 or 5 views each covering the whole screen and later, we manage the views according to our needs like hiding the views which are not needed.

Sorry if i am asking bad question. Just want to clear the things.

Comment: you use storyboard or you create all without interface builde &  code only?

Comment: we can use storyboard as well as code @muescha

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly do it that way if you wish - but you'll soon find that your view controller code is huge and is very difficult to manage since you'll have the logic for multiple views all in there and you have to handle the transition for all those separate views and so on.

But, there is nothing stopping you from doing that except for the principles of good design :)

Comment: Not to mention that if there are multiple developers working on that project, it would be a pain to solve all the conflicts.

Comment: Ur right but my point is that we can make our app run faster or not?

Comment: Your app would not be faster - and it would also be far more complex to understand.

Comment: It won't have any impact on app speed.  At least not a positive one. It is more likely that you will have bugs or visual glitches due to the complexity

Comment: @batu commenting the lines makes the work easy to solve i think.

Comment: @HarjotSingh Yes, but there would't be any conflicts to solve if it was designed to be modular in the first place.

Comment: but if the views different only by design - then you also can save duplicated code

Comment: Ok Thanks guys that answer my question @all